# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

О том, как прошёл очный этап и какие задания ждали участников в этот раз, расскажет наш корреспондент.

Answer (score 1):

**Знаки препинания расставлены верно:** О том, как прошёл очный этап и какие задания ждали участников в этот раз,  расскажет наш корреспондент.

Сложноподчиненное предложение с **однородными изъяснительными** придаточными, одиночный союз И,  союзные слова КАК и КАКИЕ, указательное слово О ТОМ.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!